# Document management in MS Dynamics CRM 2013 without Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2013, document-management

As answered in other questions you can't use the free Sharepoint Foundation 2013 for document management in MS Dynamics CRM 2013.

So I ask if there is a (good *) way of using document management in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 **without** using Sharepoint?

(* good = easy to understand for non technical users and not too complicated to manage)

I search for a way to attach all kinds of documents to different entities like:
- pictures to accounts (not profile picure)
- PDF documents to account
- ...

I know you can use **notes**.

I'm a bit confused because there are attachments on entities like email.
Can I integrate these attachment-functions on other entities like accounts?

---

**edit 18.12.2014**

Yes, you can use Sharepoint Foundation, we make it work (SP Foundation 2010).

I can use documentmanagement with sharepoint, **but not automated because the crmlistcomponent is not working.**

Maybe someone from here can help me over there:
[My Question on Sharepoint stackexchange site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/125643/35673)

Comment: While interesting, this question appears to be off-topic because it is about SharePoint, no programming. Should be moved to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @iDevlop if you read the question he wrote that he doesn't want to use sharepoint

Comment: @iDevelop thought about it, but since the "dynamics-crm-2013" tag exsits here at Stackoverflow I posted it here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attachments mechanism isn't available for common customizations, sadly. Microsoft wants us to use the notes... Except maybe ("maybe" as in "I never bothered to check due to the monstrous amount of hoops to jump through while having almost no benefits") for activity entites.

That said, you *can* use SP 2013 Foundation for document management, if you want. [Here's the step-by-step guide.](http://patricda.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/not-able-to-activate-crm-2013-list-component-in-sharepoint) We deployed a CRM 2013 + Document Management based on SP Foundation just a couple of days ago following these steps.

> To Run the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service, follow the below steps.

1. SharePoint Central Administrator
2. Under>> Service Applications
3. Manage services on server
4. Look for>>Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service is running
5. Start the service

After completing all the 5 steps

To Install List Components in SharePoint

1. Go to Site Settings
2. Under>> Web Designer Gallery>> Click on “Solutions”
3. Click on Upload solution
4. and Click on Activate

To Set Broser File handling to Permissive

1. Go to SharePoint Central Administration
2. Application Management
3. On the Ribbon click onthe General Setting
4. Web Application Generation Setting pop-up window will appear
5. Scroll down to look for Browser file handling >> Select >>Permissive
6. Click Ok, save settings and restart the server/IIS
7. try to Activate the List compoent
8. Ensure the after successful activation will enable the Deactivate button.
9. Sometime it is very annoying you need to do several click to get this working.
10. Go to CRM and add the URL into Document management, all will work fine.

FYI the "CRM 2013" list component retains the 2011 look-and-feel.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and helpful answer.

It's interesting that you can use SP Foundation because Microsoft declined it explicit in this document:
"Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 versions aren’t supported for use with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 document management."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699758(v=crm.6).aspx#BKMK_docman_op